# Sparse Autoencoder with Tanh activation from UFLDL

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pattern-recognition, sparse-matrix

I have been working of of the UFLDL tutorials (In matlab/octave) :

http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/UFLDL_Tutorial

and have been trying out the sparse autoencoder on different datasets. I tried running it on time-series data and encountered problems. Since the input data has negative values, the sigmoid activation function (1/1 + exp(-x)) is inappropriate. When substituting in tanh, the optimazion program minfunc (L-BFGS) fails (Step Size below TolX). I decreased the TolX constant dramatically with no change.
I changed the output layer to linear, kept the input layer sigmoid, but this isn't a preferable solution. The output of the autoencoder is scaled up by a constant (0.5), which boogers the cost function. So.... in short:

Why doesn't the Tanh activation function work with L-BFGS? (or is something else wrong)?

..What am I missing? Everywhere one reads it says that activation functions are pretty interchangable.  I know there are workarounds (rescale data, use FFT coefficents etc.) but I don't see why this doesn't work.

Anyway, thanks in advance to anyone who answers! First post on here, I've been reading these  types of forums more and more and am finding them increasingly helpful..

Comment: Do you know if the derivative of the tanh function was correctly derived?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+tanh

Answer (score 2):

I think I might have figured it out. Thanks to both of you for answering! The sparsity penalty uses Kullback Leibler Divergence. See this link, a bit more than half the way down the page. (Can you type in Latex in here?) It might be kinda long anyway..

http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Autoencoders_and_Sparsity

In english: The sparsity penalty tries to minimize the activations of the hidden units, but it assumes a sigmoid with output range between 0 and 1, since KL div is real only between 0 and 1.
If the average activation of tanh is 0 (which is what we would want for a sparse autoencoder) then the KL div given on that page is unhappy.
Ive looked around without luck;

is there a form of KL div which has an appropriate range for the tanh activation? Any references someone could point me to? On that site linked above, the author says many choices of sparsity penalty are ok, but doesn't elaborate further on what those other choices could be. Is it prudent to just make something up..? Or look for something thats accepted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda loosely following UFLDL, and i've ran into the same problem.

I'm trying (beta/2*m)*mean(mean(abs(a2))) to regularize the cost for sparsity, thinking that as an increase in the activation of one neuron in will be linearly matched by a decreases in the activation of the other neurons. I hope that will lead to better sparsity than KL; the low derivative of KL near p implies that as a2_j gets closer to p, further decreases in a2_j lead to smaller decreases of the cost, making it less and less likely that a2_j reaches p; a linear cost doesn't have that problem.

However i have some trouble figuring out how to modify d2 to get the correct gradients during backpropagation. You've probably found some other solution by now, but if not, this might be worth figuring out. If you (or anyone else!) figure it out, i'd love getting the answer =)

edit: d2 =   d2   + ( (network.beta / (2 * network.examples)) * exp(-a2); ) .* z2_grad; seems to give ok-ish results.

edit2: No it doesn't. Sorry 'bout that

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the sparse autoencoder algorithm following the UFLDL. I am using fortran90.

In my code I have used the tanh activation function. The `p_hat` term has been modified to range  [0,1] using,

```
p_hat = (p_hat+1.0)/2.0
```

As a consequence the sparse penalty doesn't become infeasible. My cost function converges smoothly, but the activation nodes in the hidden layer donot turn inactive (-1). I am unable to understand the phenomenon. This doesn't help my purpose of reducing dimension of the input vector.